# Numerical methods for solving nonlinear equations

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I have this equation

> $x^{5}+x^{3}+3=0$

and I'm supposed to find one root with a given accuracy using the secant method. I was wondering how I can localize a solution to an interval so I can apply the formula. I'm aware that I could separate the equation into two functions and plot both of them, but I think that can be hard sometimes when I don't have access to plotting tools like Desmos and my equation gets complicated.

Comment: Do you know the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: I do, but I considered that to be pure guessing. Sorry if Im wrong

Comment: The first thing I see is that this is positive for all positive x so I check negative numbers.  with x= -1 this is $(-1)^5+ (-1)^3+ 3= -1- 1+ 3= 1$ and with x= -2 it is $(-2)^5+ (-2)^3+ 3= -32- 8+ 3= -3$.  So there must exist an x such that $x^5+ x^3+ 3= 0$ between -1 and -2.

Comment: If we have a polynomial of the form $x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_m$ then for all roots of this polynomial (including complex roots), we have an inequality: $$ |x|\leq |a_1|+\sqrt{|a_2|}+\sqrt[3]{|a_3|}+...+\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$$Result is by Carmichael

Comment: For your polynomial, $|x|\leq 1+\sqrt[5]{3}<3$. I also meant $a_n$ instead of $a_m$.

Comment: @Jakobian seems like a useful thing; thanks

Comment: You could also use the fixed-point formula $x_{n+1}=f(x_{n})=-\sqrt[3]{\dfrac3{1+x_n^2}}$ to get from the initial guess $x_0=-1$ to the first approximation $x_1=-\sqrt[3]{\frac32}=-1.14471..$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Choose two points $x_0$and $x_1$

Here I choose $x_0=-1$ and $x_1=-2$
$$f(x_0)f(x_1)<0$$
Then apply the secant formula

$$x_n=\frac{x_{n-2}f(x_{n-1})-x_{n-1}f(x_{n-2})}{f(x_{n-1}-f(x_{n-2}))}$$

Thus $$x_2=-1.02631$$
$$x_3=-1.0464$$
$$x_4=-1.1130$$
$$x_5=-1.1045790$$
$$x_6=-1.1052901$$
$$x_7=-1.1052986$$
$$x_8=-1.1052985$$

Keep continuing until you get the root.

Comment: Is $f(x_{0})f(x_{1})<0$ the only condition that has to be met?

Comment: by this condition you get that a continuous function has a root between x_0 and x_1

Comment: @DeepeshMeena I'm not sure you are converging correctly...

Comment: ok got it This method doesn't give any guarntee of converging

Comment: @DeepeshMeena Exactly...

Comment: edited the solution by the way there was no need to downvote

Comment: It does give a guarantee, but you need certain conditions to hold first. Read up on that method (If you're interested, of course)

Comment: I meant everytime it doesn't give us guarantee we have to look for those conditions before choosing x_0 and x_1

Comment: Unfortunately I am downvoting this answer because it is not actually the secant method (as given in Don's answer). What is being used here is actually the false position (a.k.a. Regula Falsi) method, which uses the formula $$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_nf(x_b)-x_bf(x_n)}{f(x_b)-f(x_n)}$$where $x_b$ is the closest computed point to $x_n$ s.t. $f(x_b)$ and $f(x_n)$ have different signs. Although this method is guaranteed to converge, it vastly undermines the speed of convergence of the secant method, as can be seen when comparing your results to Don's.

Answer (score 1):

We take a few guesses for the function $f(x) = x^5+x^3+3$

First, we plug in $x=-1$. We find that the equation is positive, but for $x=-2$, the equation is negative.

So, we know to search in the range of $(-2,-1)$. We set $x_0=-2$ and $x_1=-1$.

Now, we use the formula for the [secant method](http://mat.iitm.ac.in/home/sryedida/public_html/caimna/transcendental/iteration%20methods/secant/secant.html):

$$x_{i+1}=x_i-\frac{f(x_i)\cdot(x_i-x_{i-1})}{f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})}$$

Applying this repeatedly gets us the sequence $$-2, -1, -1.0263157894736843, -1.119763138322457, -1.1034910955412918, -1.105259392177301, -1.105298653114797, -1.1052985459998306, -1.1052985460061695, -1.1052985460061695$$This is how we converge upon the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, an IVT is something useful:

Note that $f(-2)<0<f(-1)$, where $f(x)=x^5+x^3+3$. Hence by the IVT you have a solution in $(-2,-1)$